# How many multisets of n letters it is possible to form with k different vowels?

Tags: combinatorics

How many [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (unlike a set, a multiset allows for multiple instances for each of its elements ) of $n$ letters can I form with $k$ different vowels?

For instance, if $n=4$ and $k=2$ then some valid multisets are:

{a,a,o,o},

{a,a,a,o},

{a,i,b,d},

{u,i,k,k},

{u,i,f,g},

{i,i,u,u}

$~~~~~\vdots$

What I tried: I got stuck at the very start of the solution actually...

PS: it does not really matter to me how many letters or vowels exist. I used the alphabet just to illustrate the key idea, but it could be any other set of "letters" or "vowels".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have $C$ consonants and $V$ vowels in our alphabet and assume we want $n$-sized multisets with exactly $k$ different vowels. Choose first which of your vowels you want to include ($\binom{V}{k}$ choices). Then what is left is choosing any multiset of size $n-k$ from a set of $C+k$ symbols (the consonants and the chosen vowels). You have $\binom{C+k+(n-k)-1}{C+k-1}=\binom{C+n-1}{C+k-1}$ ways of doing that.

So $\binom{V}{k}\cdot\binom{C+n-1}{C+k-1}$ multisets in total.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct!

Comment: @MikeEarnest Because before I edited it, it was terribly wrong. I was hasty.

Comment: I see... Eh, what to do, at least OP got their answer.

Comment: Yes, I first choose my vowels and place one copy of each of them in the multiset, and then I complete the multiset with symbols coming both from consonants and the chosen vowels.

Comment: @Piita see my answer, which walks you through the solution, step by step.  My computation agrees with the computation in Don's answer.  If questions about my analysis, leave a comment/question, following my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Let $~A~$ denote the set of all vowels, and let $~B~$ denote the set of all consonants.

Index the elements of $~A~$ as $a_1, \cdots, a_r,~$ which implies that there are exactly $~r~$ vowels.

Index the elements of $~B~$ as $b_1, \cdots, b_s,~$ which implies that there are exactly $~s~$ consonants.

For any given satisfying multiset:

- let $~X_1, \cdots, X_r~$ denote the respective multiplicities of
  $~a_1, ~\cdots, ~a_r.$
- let $~Y_1, \cdots, Y_s~$ denote the respective multiplicities of
  $~b_1, ~\cdots, ~b_s.$

Now, label the following as **Constraint-1** and consider the number of solutions to Constraint-1.

- $X_1 + \cdots + X_r + Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s = n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $X_1, ~\cdots, ~X_r, ~Y_1, ~\cdots, ~Y_s \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- Exactly $~(r-k)~$ of the variables $~X_1, ~\cdots, ~X_r,~$ are equal to zero.

Constraint-1 captures the problem's constraint.  That is, exactly $~k~$ of the elements from the set $~A~$ must each have a positive integer multiplicity, and the sum of all $~(r + s)~$ multiplicities must equal $~n.~$

Further, there are exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{k}~$ ways of selecting which of the $~(r-k)~$ variables $~X_1, \cdots, X_r~$ will be set to $~0.~$

Therefore, you can **reserve** the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{k},~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that:

- $~X_1, \cdots, X_k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$
- $~X_{k+1}, \cdots, X_r~$ are all equal to $~0.~$

---

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Now, consider the alternative problem of enumerating the number of solutions to :

- $W_1 + \cdots + W_k + Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s = n-k ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $W_1, ~\cdots, ~W_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $Y_1, ~\cdots, ~Y_s \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions to the above problem is

$~\displaystyle \binom{[n-k] + [k+s-1]}{k+s-1} = \binom{n + s -1}{k+s-1}.~$

Now, consider the change of variables: $~X_i = W_i + 1 ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}.$

Then the following enumeration problem will also have exactly
$~\displaystyle \binom{n + s -1}{s+k-1}~$ solutions:

- $X_1 + \cdots + X_k + Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s = n-k+k = n.$
- $X_1, ~\cdots, ~X_k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $Y_1, ~\cdots, ~Y_s \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Therefore, the final computation of the original problem is

$$\binom{r}{k} \times \binom{n + s -1}{s+k-1}.$$